# Grails setting synchronization failed. Failed to create /Users/<username>/.grails/scripts/IdeaPrintProjectSettings.groovy

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, groovy

I have imported a grails project in Intellij. After importing the project I'm getting this error "Grails setting synchronization failed. Failed to create /Users//.grails/scripts/IdeaPrintProjectSettings.groovy"

I tried cloning the project at other location and then importing, but same issue.
I also tried invalidate Caches/restart. But the issue is still there.

Comment: Update : I downgraded the version of Intellij and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 14):

- Select File | Project Structure
- In Project Settings select 'Modules' then select your module
- In Dependencies make sure that Grails is added as a library
- Then Go to C:\Users\user.grails or in your case /Users//.grails and create an empty folder and call it scripts
- Go to IntelliJ Right click on the project | Grails | Synchronize Grails Settings

It should work now!